# Proof for the derivative of the determinant $d det(A)B = tr((cof(X))^{T}A)$

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, determinant, trace

I want to proof that the following equations is true:
$$d \space det(X)A = tr((cof(X))^{T}A)$$
I tried using Jacobi's formula, but I couldn't get anywhere.
Has anyone an Idea?

Kind Regards

$cof(X)_{i, j} = (-1)^{i+j}*det(X)_{i, j}$
 $(X)_{i, j}$ is equal to the Matrix $X$ where the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column are cancelled

Comment: With respect to what variable are you differentiating?

Comment: @Demophilus I guess X, but I am not quite sure, I found this equation in a book.

Comment: So I should imagine $d det(X)A$ as the Jacobian of the map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}: X \mapsto det(X)A$?
Maybe you could add a reference, it could help.

Comment: @Demophilus it only says Let $det:M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the determinat function and $cof$ the funktion as defined above. But is this not the derivative in $A$ "directon"? But what you said makes more sense. I am quite confused tho, what this $A$ is, is this a Matrix or a Skalar? I was hoping that someone has seen this equation before..

Comment: And this is a excerice to Partial derivative and total derivative, however there is nothing explained about the derivative of the determinant

Comment: I just noticed, but isn't this the jacobi formula but written in another way?

Comment: Well probably, it does look a lot like it. But what is $A$? And shouldn't there be a $dX$ somewhere?

Comment: I am not quite sure yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = (x_{i,j})_{i,j = 1}^n$ and let $X_{i,j}$ be the matrix obtained from $X$ by deleting the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. Then the expansion by minors formula is

$$ \det X = \sum_{j = 1}^n (-1)^{i + j} x_{i,j} \det X_{i,j}. $$

It follows that the partial derivative of $X \mapsto \det X$ with respect to $x_{i,j}$ is $(-1)^{i + j}\det X_{i,j}$ or more accurately, it is the map $A \mapsto \left( (-1)^{i + j}\det X_{i,j} \right) a_{i,j}$.

Hence the derivative at $X$ is the linear map

$$ A = (a_{i,j}) \mapsto \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \left. \frac{\partial \det}{\partial x_{i,j}} \right|_{X}(A) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \left( (-1)^{i + j} \det X_{i,j} \right)a_{i,j} = \operatorname{tr}\left( \operatorname{cof}(X)^T A \right). $$

So $(d\det)_XA = \operatorname{tr}( \operatorname{cof}(X)^T A )$.

Comment: I am not quite through understanding this fully, but is this $\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \left. \frac{\partial \det}{\partial x_{i,j}} \right|_{X}$ equal to $d \space det(X)$

Comment: Never mind I got it, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

To answer some questions I saw in the comments:

Note that cofactor expansion of determinants tells us that det is actually a polynomial in $n^2$ variables $x_{i,j}$. The derivative they are discussing is the derivative between tangent bundles from differential geometry, which in the simple case of mappings $\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is just the gradient of the function, viewed as a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^N$. The $A$ in the equation is a matrix, since the tangent space to a euclidean space is itself and we are viewing $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

My suggestion is you start playing around with the polynomial giving det on small matrices and see if you can figure out the pattern for the gradient in general.

Comment: This is really the heart of the confusion: understanding what a derivative is.

Comment: Being a polynomial is somewhat of a red-herring in this case. The main point is that the determinant is a map from the space of matrices ($\cong \mathbf{R}^{n^2}$) to the real numbers. So the derivative (at a given matrix $X$ [a point of our space]) is a linear map from matrices to real numbers. And of course since the determinant is a polynomial, it is differentiable.

Comment: Sure, when writing that I was trying to emphasize that det is a smooth function whose partial derivatives are eminently computable, since it is given by a polynomial.

Comment: I never heard about that tangent space, but it sounds interesting, so I will read up on it. But I understand the main point what you are telling so thank you!

Comment: You may wish to start with a basic real analysis book that discusses multivariate derivatives for differentiable functions between euclidean spaces, reading with your example of the determinant in mind. For example, one of the first places I learned about total derivatives was Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_.